# How can I add rows generated from object via twig to my datatable?

Tags: symfony, object, foreach, datatables, twig

This is how I add rows to my datatables:

```
  $(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    var optionText = $('.item-select option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').text();
    if (optionValue) {
      table.row.add({
        "id":       'test',
        "name":   'test',
        "type":   'test',
      }).draw();
      $('option', this).first().prop('selected', true);
    }
  });
```

I have an object `columns` :

```
array:3 [▼
  "id" => ReflectionProperty {#7030 ▶}
  "name" => ReflectionProperty {#7031 ▶}
  "type" => ReflectionProperty {#7034 ▶}
]
```

Now I like to replace the hard coded fields with the fields from my object. This is my approach:

```
  $(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    var optionText = $('.item-select option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').text();
    if (optionValue) {
      table.row.add({
        {% for key, value in columns %}
        {   "{{ key }}": 'test'},
        {% endfor %}
      }).draw();
      $('option', this).first().prop('selected', true);
    }
  });
```

The error in the console is this:

> SyntaxError: expected property name, got '{'

Comment: Are you sure that SyntaxError is in the posted code?

Comment: Are you mixing twig and js here: `{% for key, value in columns %}`?

Comment: @SilvioQ No, I am not sure, but this error is only occurring when I use the loop

Comment: @BenjaminKozlowski I am using this way often and it usually works very well, but not here

Comment: @SilvioQ But I think the problem is that after `row.add({` there comes again `{` and I do not know how to write it differently

Comment: Try `"{{ key }}": 'test', ` (without curly bracket `{`)

Comment: @SilvioQ Yes! THis worked!! Great, thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove curly brackets ...

```
  $(document).on('change', '.item-select', function() {
    var optionValue = $(this).val();
    var optionText = $('.item-select option[value="'+optionValue+'"]').text();
    if (optionValue) {
      table.row.add({
        {% for key, value in columns %}
          "{{ key }}": 'test',
        {% endfor %}
      }).draw();
      $('option', this).first().prop('selected', true);
    }
  });
```